# Numerology with Ramanujan's pi formula

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, sequences-and-series

Given Ramanujan's famous $\frac1{\pi}$ formula $$\frac 1\pi=\frac {2\sqrt2}{99^2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {(4k)!}{k!^4}\frac {26390k+1103}{396^{4k}}$$

which is a level 2 Ramanujan-Sato series. It can also be expressed as
$$\frac{1}{\pi} =\frac{192 \sqrt 2}{(396^2)^{3/2}} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \tbinom{2k}{k}\tbinom{2k}{k}\tbinom{4k}{2k}\frac{2\cdot58\cdot15015k+72798}{(396^4)^k}$$

where $\binom{n}{k}$ is the *binomial coefficient*. In this form, its affinity is clear to the following level 8 Ramanujan-Sato series,

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{\pi}&=\frac{192\sqrt{2}}{(396^2+4)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k}\,s_2(k)\,\frac{58\cdot15015k+(72798-37/4)}{(396^2+4)^k}\\
\frac{1}{\pi}&=\frac{192\sqrt{2}}{(396^2+8)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k}\,s_3(k)\,\frac{58\cdot15015k+(72798-37/2)}{(396^2+8)^k}\\
\frac{1}{\pi}&=\frac{192\sqrt{2}}{(396^2+16)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k}\,s_4(k)\,\frac{58\cdot15015k+(72798-37)}{(396^2+16)^k}\\
\frac{1}{\pi}&\overset{\color{red}?}=\frac{192\sqrt{2}}{(396^2+32)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k}\,s_5(k)\,\frac{58\cdot15015k+(72798-2\cdot37)}{(396^2+32)^k}\\
\frac{1}{\pi}&\overset{\color{red}?}=\frac{192\sqrt{2}}{(396^2+64)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k}\,s_6(k)\,\frac{58\cdot15015k+(72798-4\cdot37)}{(396^2+64)^k}\end{aligned}$$

and integer sequences $s_n(k)$ starting with $k=0$,

$$\begin{aligned}
s_2(k)&=\sum_{j=0}^k\tbinom{k}{2j}\tbinom{2j}{j}\tbinom{2j}{j}=1, 1, 5, 13, 61, 221,\dots\\
s_3(k)&=\sum_{j=0}^k\tbinom{k}{2j}\tbinom{2k-4j}{k-2j}\tbinom{2j}{j}=1, 2, 8, 32, 148, 712,\dots\\
s_4(k)&=\sum_{j=0}^k\tbinom{k}{j}\tbinom{2k-2j}{k-j}\tbinom{2j}{j}=1, 4, 20, 112, 676, 4304,\dots\\
s_5(k)&=1, 8, 68, 608, 5668, 54688, 542864,\dots\\
s_6(k)&=1, 16, 260, 4288, 71716, 1215296, 20848016,\dots
\end{aligned}$$

> **Q:** Are all the terms of $s_5(k)$ and $s_6(k)$ integers as well, and does it have a closed-form?

**P.S.** I have already checked the OEIS.

Comment: I've re-indexed $s_n(k)$ to match the $396^2+2^n$ in the denominators, I hope this okay. Another reason is for me to ask: if we treat the very first formula of Ramanujan corresponding to $s_0(k)$ then what is the missing series that might be associated with $s_1(k)$?

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: I have also checked $396^2+2$ as a denominator. However, $s_1(k)$ seem to involve rationals already. (Notice that the second term of $s_n(k)$ for $n>1$ start with $1,2,4,8,16$.)

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: I just found the general case. Kindly see below.

Comment: Because the title said Numerology I thought you might be asking something about the Freemasons or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(*Too long for a comment*.) After staring hard at my question and recalling an old [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1952204/the-chudnovsky-pi-formula-1-pi-revisited) of mine, I made an inspired guess and found,

> Level 8

$$\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{192\sqrt{2}}{(396^2+4\color{blue}\alpha)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k \color{blue}\alpha^{k-2j} \tbinom{k}{2j}\tbinom{2j}{j}\tbinom{2j}{j} \frac{58\cdot15015k+72798-37\color{blue}\alpha/4}{(396^2+4\color{blue}\alpha)^k}$$

for ***general*** real $\alpha$, so turns out it is unnecessary to restrict it to powers of $2$. (Thus, $s_5(k)$ and $s_6(k)$ ***do*** have a closed-form and are integer sequences.)

> Level 9

Similarly, the Chudnovsky formula (a level 1 Ramanujan-Sato) yields,

$$\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{12}{(640320-4\color{blue}\alpha)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k \color{blue}\alpha^{k-3j} \tbinom{k}{3j}\tbinom{2j}{j}\tbinom{3j}{j} \frac{163A\,k+B+1448\color{blue}\alpha/3}{(-640320+4\color{blue}\alpha)^k}$$

where $A=1114806, B=13591409$.

---

(***Added later.***) Now that I know what to look for, one can find other families.

> Level 6

For example, starting with H. H. Chan, W. Zudilin, et al's

$$\frac1{\pi}=\frac{192\sqrt3}{(2\cdot140^2)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}k\sum_{j=0}^k\tbinom{k}{j}^3\,\frac{140(561k+53)}{(2\cdot140^2)^k}$$

mentioned in H. H. Chan and S. Cooper's *"Rational analogues of Ramanujan's series for 1/π"*, we find,
$$\frac1{\pi}=\frac{192\sqrt3}{(2\cdot140^2+4\color{blue}\alpha)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}k\sum_{j=0}^k \color{blue}\alpha^{k-j}\tbinom{k}{j}\sum_{m=0}^j\tbinom{j}{m}^3\,\frac{140(561k+53)-13\color{blue}\alpha/4}{(2\cdot140^2+4\color{blue}\alpha)^k}$$

> Level 10

$$\frac1{\pi}=\frac{16\sqrt{5}}{\sqrt{19}(76^2+4\color{blue}\alpha)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}k\sum_{j=0}^k \color{blue}\alpha^{k-j}\tbinom{k}{j}\tbinom{2j}{j}^{-1}\sum_{m=0}^j\tbinom{j}{m}^4\,\frac{19^2(408k+47)-157\color{blue}\alpha/4}{(76^2+4\color{blue}\alpha)^k}$$

**P.S.** However, I do not have a rigorous proof for these families and the relevant literature do not seem to address general $\alpha$.

**Note:** The level $\color{red}m$ is given by an eta quotient $\frac{\eta(\tau)}{\eta(\color{red}m\,\tau)}$. For example, define

$$\lambda(\tau) =-6+\big(\tfrac{\eta^2(3\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(\color{red}9\tau)}\big)^6 -27 \big(\tfrac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(\color{red}9\tau)}{\eta^2(3\tau)}\big)^6$$

so $\lambda\Big(\tfrac{3+\sqrt{-163}}{6}\Big)=-640320$ is level $9$.

Comment: This is a very naive comment, but have you tried to derive the RHS with respect to  $ \alpha $?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: I wouldn't know where to start. It was luck and persistence that I detected a pattern.

Comment: By the way, when you say 'for general  $ \alpha $ ', is  $ \alpha $  supposed to be an integer or any non negative real number ? Cause if it has to be an integer, maybe one should check  $ 1 $-periodicity and all the Fourier related stuff.

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN: For _any_ non-zero real number $\alpha$, positive or negative, as long as the denominator does not vanish, or the denominator becomes so small that the series no longer converges

Comment: FWIW, if we denote by $s_k(\alpha)$ the sum $\sum_{j=0}^k\alpha^{k-2j}\binom{k}{2j}\binom{2j}{j}\binom{2j}{j}$ in your formula, the Wilf-Zeilberger methods seem to produce a recurrence 


$\alpha(\alpha^2-16)(k+1)(k+2)s_k(\alpha)-(3\alpha^2-16)(k+2)^2s_{k+1}(\alpha)+\alpha(3k^2+15k+19)s_{k+2}(\alpha)-(k+3)^2s_{k+3}(\alpha)=0$

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko: I have an infinite sequence of integers related to this post and perhaps to $\zeta(5)$. Would you be able to find its recurrence if you have enough terms of the sequence?

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII give me some context and I can try. My contact details are on my homepage (link in the profile).

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko: I've asked it in another question to format it properly. Kindly see [this post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/265688/about-a-ramanujan-sato-formula-of-level-10-a-recurrence-and-zeta5).

Comment: Very nice stuff! May you just specify in which sense you use the word «level» here?

Comment: @Wolfgang: I've added a note regarding the "level". Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thank you, that helps. So you use it in fact the same way as Michael Somos in his collection of eta identities. Didn't occur to me earlier...

Comment: @Wolfgang: That is also how H. H. Chan and S. Cooper use it in their _"Rational analogues of Ramanujan's series for 1/π"_. :)

Answer (score 3):

(*Per S. Cooper's request*.)

> **I. Table relating level $1$ with level $9$**.

The general form apparently is,

$$\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{12}{(C)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k} \tbinom{3k}{k}\tbinom{6k}{3k} \frac{\color{red}3A\,k+B}{(-C^3)^k}$$
and,
$$\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{12}{(C-4\color{blue}\alpha)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k \color{blue}\alpha^{k-3j} \tbinom{k}{3j}\tbinom{2j}{j}\tbinom{3j}{j} \frac{A\,k+B+N\color{blue}\alpha/3}{(-C+4\color{blue}\alpha)^k}$$

for general real $\color{blue}\alpha$ and where,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
d&A&B&C&N\\
\hline
11&154/9&5&32&4/3\\
19&114&25&96&4\\
43 &5418 &789 &960 &24\\
67 &87234 &10177 &5280 &76\\
163 &181713378 &13591409 &640320 &1448\\
\hline
\end{array}$$

The variables $A,B,C$ are known to have closed-form expressions in terms of $d$. Presumably $N$ should have as well.

**P.S.** Note also the equivalent forms,

$$s_k(\color{blue}\alpha)=\sum_{j=0}^k \color{blue}\alpha^{k-3j} \tbinom{k}{3j}\tbinom{2j}{j}\tbinom{3j}{j}=\sum_{j=0}^k \color{blue}\alpha^{k-3j} \tbinom{k}{j}\tbinom{k-j}{j}\tbinom{k-2j}{j}$$

where the latter form is used in H. Chan and S. Cooper's paper "*Rational analogues of Ramanujan's series for 1/π"*. The case $\alpha=-3$,

$$s_k(-3) = 1, -3, 9, -21, 9, 297, -2421$$

is one of the [six sporadic sequences](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/257642843_Sporadic_sequences_modular_forms_and_new_series_for_1p) studied by Zagier and Cooper.

> **II. Table relating level $2$ with level $8$**.

The general form apparently is,

$$\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{192\sqrt{2}}{(C)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k} \tbinom{2k}{k}\tbinom{4k}{2k} \frac{\color{red}2A\,k+B}{(C^2)^k}$$
and,
$$\frac{1}{\pi}=\frac{192\sqrt{2}}{(C+4\color{blue}\alpha)^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\tbinom{2k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k \color{blue}\alpha^{k-2j} \tbinom{k}{2j}\tbinom{2j}{j}\tbinom{2j}{j} \frac{A\,k+B-M\color{blue}\alpha/4}{(C+4\color{blue}\alpha)^k}$$

for general real $\color{blue}\alpha$ and where,

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
d&A&B&C&M\\
\hline
6&\sqrt2&\sqrt2/4&(4\sqrt3)^2&\sqrt2/12\\
10&10&2&12^2&1/3\\
18 &70\sqrt6 &21\sqrt6/2 &28^2 &\sqrt6/2\\
22 &385\sqrt2 &209\sqrt2/4 &(12\sqrt{11})^2 &17\sqrt2/12\\
58 &870870&72798&396^2&37\\
\hline
\end{array}$$