# Transformations of Ramanujan's 1/pi formulas $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s(n)\frac{An+ B}{C^n}$ and Monster moonshine functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, modular-forms, limits-and-convergence

Someone with many papers on Ramanujan's work asked me how I managed to find the closed-forms for the binomial sums of level $10$ in a recent [MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446654/12905). (A colleague of his wasn't able to find them.) I found about six general transformation methods, one of which is relevant to his question.

---

**I. Method 1**

Given the *binomial coefficient* $\binom{n}{k}$, some free parameters $p, r,$ and a sequence $s_1(n)$. Define a second sequence as,

$$s_2(m) = \sum_{n=0}^m (-r)^{m-pn} \binom{m+pn}{m-pn} s_1(n)$$

Then we have the transformation,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s_1(n)\,\frac{An+ B}{C^n}=\frac{C^{1/p}}{\alpha-r}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} s_2(m)\,\frac{A/p\,m+ B+D_1}{\alpha^m}$$

where we find $\alpha$ and $D_1$ as,

$$C^{1/p}=\Big(\sqrt{\alpha}+\frac{r}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\Big)^2$$
$$D_1 = \frac{r\,(A/p-2B)}{\alpha+r}$$

---

**II. Level 2**

As an example of the method, consider Ramanujan's formula,

$$\frac1{\pi}=\frac{2\sqrt2}{99^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty  \binom{2k}{k}^2\binom{4k}{2k} \frac{26390k+1103}{396^{4k}}$$

so we have $A =26390, B=1103, C = 396^4.$ But we also have the known relation,

$$j_{2A}=\Big(\sqrt{j_{2B}}+\frac{64}{\sqrt{j_{2B}}}\Big)^2= 396^4$$

where $j_M$ is one of the "moonshine functions" (which span a linear space of [**163** dimensions](https://sites.google.com/site/tpiezas/0022)). We could choose other $p,r$, but for this case, the appropriate choice is $p=1$ and $r=64$, and giving us the 12th power of the fundamental unit $U_{29}$,

$$\alpha = j_{2B} =  64\left(\frac{5+\sqrt{29}}2\right)^{12}$$

With $\alpha,p,r$ known, then $D_1$ follows, and we get the transformed formula,

$$\frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{16\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{\alpha}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty s_2(k)\, \frac{99^2\sqrt{29}\left(k+\frac12\right)-24184}{\alpha^k}$$

using the second sequence,

$$s_2(k) = \sum_{j=0}^k(-64)^{k-j}\binom{k+j}{k-j}\binom{2j}{j}^2\binom{4j}{2j}$$

See also [Ramanujan-Sato series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series#Level_2) for level **2**.

---

**III. Level 10**

A known formula is,

$$\frac{1}{\pi} = \frac{5}{76\sqrt{95}}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^4\frac{408k+47}{76^{2k}}$$

However, there are the relations,

$$j_{10A} = \left(\sqrt{j_{10B}} + \frac{4}{\sqrt{j_{10B}}}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{j_{10D}} + \frac{-1}{\sqrt{j_{10D}}}\right)^2 = 76^2$$

From these, we can get $j_{10B}$ and $j_{10D}$. And just like before, we chose $p = 1$, then $r_B = 4$ and $r_D = -1$. In addition to the 1st sequence, and with minor change of variables, this gives us the 2nd and 3rd sequences,

\begin{align}
s_{10A}(k) &=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^4 = 1,2,18,164,1810,\dots \\
s_{10B}(k) &=\sum_{j=0}^k(-4)^{k-j}\binom{k+j}{k-j}\sum_{m=0}^j \binom{j}{m}^4 = 1,−2,10,−68,514,−4100,\dots\\
s_{10D}(k) &= \sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k+j}{k-j} \sum_{m=0}^j \binom{j}{m}^4 = 1,3,25,267,3249,\dots
\end{align}

However, there is still $j_{10C}.$ (All four are found in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446654/12905).) But since its relation with $j_{10A}$ is only a near-square, deriving its sequence $s_{10C}(k)$ is trickier but doable (which can be discussed in another post).

Using Method 1, this level 10 formula can be transformed just like Ramanujan's level 2 formula. So with four sequences and subscripts $\small{A, B, C, D}$, this implies there are at least **four** basic families of 1/pi for level $10$.

---

**IV. Questions**

1. I found Method 1 empirically. I tested it with various "seed" sequences (even the Fibonacci sequence and others) with free parameters $p,r$ chosen carefully and, as long as it is within the radius of convergence, it seems valid. So when it works, then ***why*** does it work?
2. For prudence, when testing the method, I only chose small integers for parameters $p,r$. But how arbitrary can they be?

Answer (score 1):

(*This is an addendum to add more details but not to clutter the main post*.)

As more evidence, the method gives **alternative** closed-forms for the level-$6$ binomial sums. To recall, we have,

$$j_{6A} = \left(\sqrt{j_{6B}} + \frac{-\color{blue}1}{\sqrt{j_{6B}}}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{j_{6C}} + \frac{\color{blue}8}{\sqrt{j_{6C}}}\right)^2$$

Using the method to generate a new sequence from the "seed", we chose $p=1,$ then $r=-\color{blue}1$ and $r=\color{blue}8.$ The 1st sequence is the "seed",

\begin{align}
s_{6A}(k) 
&=\binom{2k}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^3\quad\quad\\ 
&=1, 4, 60, 1120, 24220,\ldots\quad
\end{align}

and we find an alternative form for the 2nd sequence (which are [*Apéry's numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_theorem#Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_proof) $b_n$),

\begin{align}
s_{6B}(k) &=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^2\binom{k+j}{j}^2\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k(\color{blue}1)^{k-j}\,\binom{k+j}{k-j}\binom{2j}j\sum_{m=0}^k \binom{j}{m}^3\\ 
&=1, 5, 73, 1445, 33001,\ldots\\
\end{align}

and for the 3rd as,

\begin{align}
s_{6C}(k) &= (-1)^k \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^2 \binom{2(k-j)}{k-j} \binom{2j}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^k(-\color{blue}8)^{k-j}\,\binom{k+j}{k-j}\binom{2j}j\sum_{m=0}^k \binom{j}{m}^3\\ 
&=1, -4, 28, -256, 2716,\ldots
\end{align}

The 4th using $j_{6D}$ is trickier since its relation with $j_{6A}$ is only a near-square but again, still doable. But this makes me wonder if the level-$10$ analogues have *simpler* single-summation versions.