# On level-$12$ of the McKay-Thompson series of the Monster and the Domb numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, sequences-and-series, modular-forms, binomial-coefficients, monster

(*This continues from [level 10](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446654/12905).*) Given some [moonshine functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%E2%80%93Sato_series) $j_{N}$. There are nice *descending* and consistent relations for levels $6m$ with $m= 2,3,5,$

$$j_{12A} = \left(\sqrt{j_{12H}} + \frac{\color{blue}{1}}{\sqrt{j_{12H}}}\right)^2 =\left(\sqrt{j_{12E}} + \frac{\color{blue}4}{\sqrt{j_{12E}}}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{j_{12B}} + \frac{\color{blue}3}{\sqrt{j_{12B}}}\right)^2+4$$

$$j_{18B} = \left(\sqrt{j_{18E}} + \frac{\color{blue}{1}}{\sqrt{j_{18E}}}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{j_{18A}} + \frac{\color{blue}3}{\sqrt{j_{18A}}}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{j_{18C}} + \frac{\color{blue}2}{\sqrt{j_{18C}}}\right)^2+4$$

$$j_{30B} = \left(\sqrt{j_{30F}} + \frac{\color{blue}{1}}{\sqrt{j_{30F}}}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{j_{30C}} + \frac{\color{blue}2}{\sqrt{j_{30C}}}\right)^2 = \left(\sqrt{j_{30A}} + \frac{\color{blue}1}{\sqrt{j_{30A}}}\right)^2+4$$

As before, if the "auxiliary" integer sequence for the LHS function is known, then one gets at least ***four*** sequences for that level by using the blue numbers. Each can then be used to find formulas for $1/\pi.$

---

**I. Level-12 functions**

For brevity, this is only for level-12. Given the Dedekind eta function $\eta(\tau)$, define,

\begin{align}
j_{12A}(\tau) &= \left(\frac{\eta^2(2\tau)\,\eta^2(6\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(3\tau)\,\eta(4\tau)\,\eta(12\tau)}\right)^{6} \\
j_{12B}(\tau) &= \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(4\tau)\,\eta(6\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)\,\eta(3\tau)\,\eta(12\tau)}\right)^{4} \\
j_{12E}(\tau) &= \left(\frac{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(3\tau)}{\eta(4\tau)\,\eta(12\tau)}\right)^{2} \\
j_{12H}(\tau) &= \left(\frac{\eta(3\tau)\,\eta(4\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(12\tau)}\right)^{4} \\
j_{12I}(\tau)\, &= \left(\frac{\eta^2(4\tau)\,\eta(6\tau)}{\eta(2\tau)\,\eta^2(12\tau)}\right)^{2}  
\end{align}

Conway and Norton found these five moonshine functions obey (or a version thereof),

$$j_{12A}+2j_{12I} = j_{12B}+j_{12E}+j_{12H}+8$$

---

**II. Sequences**

From "*[The Level 12 Analogue of Ramanujan's Function $k$](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291553159_THE_LEVEL_12_ANALOGUE_OF_RAMANUJAN%27S_FUNCTION_k)*", it turns out the auxiliary sequence for $j_{12A}(\tau)$ are the *Domb numbers*. (Edit: In [Chan et al's paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870803002548?via%3Dihub), it also appears in level-6). From this sequence, we can derive three more,

\begin{align}
s_{12A}(k) &= \sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}^2 \binom{2k-2j}{k-j} \binom{2j}{j}\\
s_{12H}(j) &=\sum_{k=0}^j (-u)^{j-k}\binom{j+k}{j-k}\,s_{12A}(k)\\
s_{12E}(j) &=\sum_{k=0}^j (-v)^{j-k}\binom{j+k}{j-k}\,s_{12A}(k)\\
s_{12B}(n) &=\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=0}^j(-w)^{n-j}\,\binom{n+j}{n-j}\binom{j}{k}\binom{2j}{j}\binom{2k}{k}^{-1}s_{12A}(k)
\end{align}

where $u = \color{blue}1$, $v = \color{blue}4$, $w = \color{blue}3.$ Using the variable $n$ for uniformity, the first few terms are,

\begin{align}
s_{12A}(n) &=1, 4, 28, 256, 2716, 31504,\ldots\\
s_{12H}(n) &=1, 3, 17, 139, 1305, 13307,\ldots\\
s_{12E}(n) &=1, 0, -4, 16, -36, 32, 64, 0,  -2404,\ldots\\
s_{12B}(n) &=1, -1, 1, 7, -103, 1015, -9087, 78615,\ldots
\end{align}

such that all $s_{12}(0) = 1.$ The sequences $(s_{12A},\,s_{12H},\, s_{12E},\, s_{12B})$ have an $m$-term recurrence relation with $m = 3,6,6,7,$ respectively (similar to [level-10](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446654/12905)).

---

**III. Pi formulas**

**A.** These four sequences can generate new formulas for $1/\pi$ of level 12. For example, let $\tau = \frac16\sqrt{-15}$, then,

\begin{align}
j_{12A}(\tau) &= 64\\
j_{12D}(\tau) &= (4+\sqrt{15})^2\\
j_{12E}(\tau) &= 4(2+\sqrt{3})^2\\
j_{12B}(\tau) &= 3(2+\sqrt{5})^2\qquad
\end{align}

and we get,

\begin{align}
\quad\frac1{\pi} &= \sqrt{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{12A}(n)\,\frac{\;5n+1}{(64)^{n+1/2}}\\
\frac1{\pi} &= \frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{12D}(n)\,\frac{5n+1+\psi_1\quad}{\big((4+\sqrt{15})^2\big)^{n+1/2}}\\
\frac1{\pi} &= \sqrt4\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{12E}(n)\,\frac{5n+1+\psi_2}{\,\big(4(2+\sqrt{3})^2\big)^{n+1/2}}\\
\frac1{\pi} &= \sqrt{3}\,\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{12B}(n)\,\frac{An+B+\psi_3}{\,\big(3(2+\sqrt{5})^2\big)^{n+1/2}}
\end{align}

where $\psi_1 = \frac{3}{8\,(4+\sqrt{15})}$ and $\psi_2 = \frac{3}{4\,(2+\sqrt{3})}.$ (**Note**: The fourth to be added later.)

**B.** Furthermore, if within the radius of convergence, it seems that,

$$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{12A}(n)\,\frac{1}{\;\big(j_{12A}\big)^{n+1/2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{12H}(n)\,\frac{1}{\;\big(j_{12H}\big)^{n+1/2}} = \\ \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{12E}(n)\,\frac{1}{\;\big(j_{12E}\big)^{n+1/2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty s_{12B}(n)\,\frac{1}{\;\big(j_{12B}\big)^{n+1/2}}$$

though level-12 is special since $x$ has a closed-form,

$$x=\frac{\eta^4(2\tau)\,\eta^4(6\tau)}{\eta(\tau)\,\eta(3\tau)\,\eta(4\tau)\,\eta(12\tau)}$$

---

**IV. Questions**

1. I have no proof for the pi formulas above, and other similar level-12 I’ve tested. Are they indeed true? (Cooper's paper cited does not include any pi formulas.)
2. As usual, do the sequences' closed-forms for level-12 have simpler versions just like for level-6?

**Edit.** Turns out the paper "*Domb’s numbers and Ramanujan–Sato type series for 1/pi*" by H. Chan, S. Chan, and Z. Liu has the first sequence and pi formula, but not the other three sequences.)